# Returning an empty FlatList

Tags: react-native

I'am trying to get the data from an api , but it gives me an empty flat list could someone help me please ,

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/actualite`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res : [...this.state.data, ...res],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
      alert(this.state.data)
  };
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1q3.png)

Comment: can you `console.log` res and share it as well.

Comment: @aytek I did the alert but its empty

Comment: Check your API then, it's not a react-native issue.

Comment: the api works vers well I ll search a screen for the api , please give it a look

Comment: open this link in your browser -> http://localhost:8080/actualite and paste the response here.